# html checkbox values to array and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

здравствуйте, есть несколько чекбоксов, как показано на скриншоте

как их можно отправить ajax формой, массивом, на подобии array = name: prop.checked (количество чекбоксов не фиксировано)

то есть array = 2:'false', 22:'true', 20:'true';

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: задайте name так array[2] и с остальными элементами также

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто пройти по всем чекбоксам циклом и проверить каждый отдельно, только в вашем случае думаю стоит будет уточнить селектор, в моем случае будет находить все чекбоксы на странице:

```js
var data = {};
$('[type="checkbox"]').each(function(index, el) {
 data[$(el).attr('name')] = $(el).is(":checked");
});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="22" checked>
<input type="checkbox" name="20" checked>
```

Дальше объект `data` передаете в `ajax` и всё.